# Calculate the number of days of a date range occur between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have a datasheet that contains a list of start and end dates for a task. I need to calculate how many days between the start date and end date are part of our Christmas break (11th December to 7th January)

So for example,when start date is 10/12/2012 and end date is 12/01/2013, 28 of the days are between those dates. when the start date is 15/12/2012 and the end date is 12/03/2013, then 22 days of days are between those dates. If the start date is 10/12/2012 and the end date is 12/01/2014, 56 of the days are between those dates (because there's two years of the range).

I need to do this with a formula because of the requirements that I've been set. 
Initially I decided to use the number of times Christmas Day (25th December) occurs and just calculate 4 weeks per occurrence.

The formula I used was

```
=FLOOR((E12-A25)/365,1)+IF(OR(MONTH(E12)=12,
       MONTH(A25)=12),
       IF(AND(DAY(A25)<=25,DAY(E12)>=25),1,0),
       IF(OR(MONTH(A25)>=12,
       IF(MONTH(E12)<MONTH(A25),
          MONTH(E12)+12,
          MONTH(E12))>=12),1,0))*28
```

But obviously this doesn't help if the range start and end date falls between those two dates.

Any suggestions? I'm at a dead end

Comment: what is the problem ? is getting 56 days between 10/12/2012 and 12/01/2014 a problem?

Comment: No, that's the correct answer to get. The issue is that the current formula doesn't calculate it properly. The formula only checks to see if 25th December happens between two dates. If the range was 11/12/2012 to 23/12/2012 it would return 0. It should return 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date math on the second example is wrong -- there are 24 days in that range, not 22.

I can get you there for *one* holiday period:

LET:

- A1 contain the holiday start (11-Dec-2012)
- A2 contain the holiday end (7-Jan-2013)
- B1 contain the start date
- B2 contain the end date

FORMULA:

```
=MAX(MIN(A2+1,B2+1),A1) - MIN(MAX(A1,B1),A2+1)
```

The formula basically finds the overlapping date range, if there is one, and subtracts to get the number of whole days. The "+1" is because your "end dates" are actually inclusive, so for date math you need to have the holiday ending on 8 Jan, not 7 Jan, to capture that last day.

But this only works for a single year's holiday. You could store holiday ranges in other cells and use the same formula and add them all up, but you'll be limited to however many years you set up.

Comment: thanks richardtallent for you detailed answer. This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: I did realise that my question was a bit off though. I have ended up using this `=IF(AND(B1>=A1,B1<=A2),28,MAX(MIN(A2+1,B2+1),A1) - MIN(MAX(A1,B1),A2+1))` as I realised if the start date fell within that period, I needed to move everything back 28 days regardless. Thought I'd leave this here for anyone else who gets stuck in the same way (or to be corrected if I've gotten the idea wrong again) :)

Answer (score 0):

This formula will count dates between 11th December and 7th January inclusive within **any** date range, even across multiple years

`=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&B2)),"mmdd")+0>=1211)+(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&B2)),"mmdd")+0<=107))`

where your start date is in B1 and end date in B2

This converts every date in the range to a number , e.g. 1st Dec becomes 1201, 4th March becomes 304, then it counts those dates that are either greater or equal to 1207 (7th December) or smaller than or equal to 107 (7th January), so that will give 56 for your last example

You can shorten the formula if you subtract 7 from every date (based on 7th January as the end date) then you only need to check that resultant numbers are >= 1204, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(B1-7&":"&B2-7)),"mmdd")+0>=1204)+0)`

.....and a third option which should also give the same result, closer to richardtallent's approach - gets the number of years and multiplies by 28 and then adjusts the figures based on the start/end date

`=(YEAR(B1-7)-YEAR(B2-7)+1)*28-MAX(0,B2-DATE(YEAR(B2-7),12,11))-MIN(28,DATE(YEAR(B1-7)+1,1,7)-B1)`